# how do you create custom buttons with highcharts that each data buttons calls anather php script for its data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create custom selectors with highcharts. Based on which buttons on the top right clicked, I need to call different php file that outputs different data sets. For example, the following script reads only one file and zooms in/out based on one file data. I have 6 different files, 1) 5 minute data for one day 2) hourly data for one month, 3) daily data for 3 months 4) weekly data for 6 months etc. Based on which buttons is clicked on the top left corner I need to issue soemthing like this:

I am trying to create my own buttons as this jsfiddle but in each button I need to call another external file to graph my chart:
    http://jsfiddle.net/YQnJM/4/

I have tried something like this:

```
    (function() {

    var genOptions = function(data) {
        return {
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },
            rangeSelector : {
                enabled:false
            },
            series : data
        };
    }
$.getJSON('db.php', function(data) {  
        var options = genOptions(data);
        var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
        normalState = new Object();
        normalState.stroke_width = null;
        normalState.stroke = null;
        normalState.fill = null;
        normalState.padding = null;
        normalState.style = hash('text-decoration', 'underline');

        hoverState = new Object();
        hoverState = normalState;


        pressedState = new Object();
        pressedState = normalState;
        chart_1DButton = chart.renderer.button('1D', 52, 10, function() {
        var date = Date.now();
        var date2 = new Date();
        date2.setHours(0);
        date2.setMinutes(0);
        date2.setSeconds(0);
        date2.setMilliseconds(0);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(date2, date, true);
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                $.getJSON('db_cpu_1_day.php', function(data1) {
                options.series[0].setData(data1);

            });
        unselectButtons();
        chart_1DButton.setState(2);
        }, normalState, hoverState, pressedState);

        chart_1DButton.add();
function unselectButtons() {
            chart_1DButton.setState(0);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) you can check which button is selected by code:

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
            console.log(this);
            if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined')
            {
              alert('count: '+e.rangeSelectorButton.count + 'text: ' +e.rangeSelectorButton.text + ' type:' + e.rangeSelectorButton.type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can render your own buttons by:

```
normalState = new Object();
        normalState.stroke_width = null;
        normalState.stroke = null;
        normalState.fill = null;
        normalState.padding = null;
        //normalState.r = null;
        normalState.style = hash('text-decoration', 'underline');

        hoverState = new Object();
        hoverState = normalState;


        pressedState = new Object();
        pressedState = normalState;

chart_1MButton = chart.renderer.button('1M', 96, 10, function() {
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1344527940000, 1346342400000, true);
        unselectButtons();
        chart_1MButton.setState(2);
    }, normalState, hoverState, pressedState);

    chart_1MButton.add();

 function unselectButtons() {
            chart_1MButton.setState(0);
}
```

Comment: can you illustrate this by fiddle using 2 custom buttons with two different external files?

Comment: In my example you can call ajax, inseatd of instrucitons, which are example, then use chart.addSeries() or chart.addPoint (depends on your data format)

Comment: I'm not following it, I really need an example.

Comment: chart_1MButton = chart.renderer.button('1M', 96, 10, function() {
       $.ajax()
    }, normalState, hoverState, pressedState);

    chart_1MButton.add();

Comment: @Sebastioan Bochan, can you please illustrate this in jsfiddle?

Comment: @ Sebastian Bochan, hash is not defined

Comment: I am having all kinds of problem with this. Now getting unselectButtons not defined.

Comment: Updated, you need to prepare functon wich will change state.

Comment: since I will be calling an external file to load the data, I really dont need  this "chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1346256000000, 1346342400000,true);", when I commented it out it wont work. Also, I need to have all of my buttons to have borders and background colour. Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/YQnJM/4/, any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen mail which I send you, in the morning ?

Comment: yes, thank you so much. In my opinion, this really should be well doumented on highcharts site?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
var urls = {
    '1m': 'url1',
    '3m': 'url2',
    '6m': 'url3',
    'YTD': 'url4',
    '1y': 'url5',
    'All': 'url6'
};

$('.highcharts-button').on('click', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('tspan').text()
    $.getJSON(urls[selected], function(json) {
        // set new data
    });
});
```

This way you'll get the url according to the selected button.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sPwjN/)

Comment: I really appreciate this. Can you include two examples under this     $.getJSON(urls[selected], function(json) {
for using different file for two different buttons?

Comment: tspan is not good solution because in IE7 which use VML, it will not work.

Comment: @Ricardo Lohmann, can you take a look at my original post. I've update with some new code? The idea is, if I click on the button, I need to load new data, need to replace the series data. How could I do this?